# Can't connect to Docker user defined bridge network

Tags: docker, networking, prometheus

I've been struggling with this for a while, maybe someone might have some insight...I've created a docker bridge network:

```
docker network create -d bridge prometheus-network
```

in which I'm running both Prometheus and cAdvisor containers, created as such:
Prometheus:

```
docker run -d --net=prometheus-network --name=prometheus-server -p 9090:9090 -v /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml prom/prometheus
```

cAdvisor:

```
docker run -d --net=prometheus-network --name=cadvisor -p 8080:8080 --volume=/:/rootfs:ro --volume=/var/run:/var/run:ro --volume=/sys:/sys:ro --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro --volume=/dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro --privileged --device=/dev/kmsg gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor:latest
```

I can see both up and running and can connect to the Prometheus web UI.  From there, though, it shows the cAdvisor connection being refused (I have one other container in the network as well, which is also being refused)

here is the prometheus.yml file, with the two targets defined:

```
global:
  evaluation_interval: 15s
  scrape_interval: 15s
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: adapters
    static_configs:
      - labels:
          namespace: adapters
        targets:
          - tiingo:9080
  - job_name: cadvisor
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8080']
```

and what I'm seeing:
[image]

Is there some other networking step here that I might be missing??  Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 1):

When you connect to `localhost` you will connect to the `localhost` of the current container. Within user-defined docker networks you can use container names as hostnames thanks to Docker service discovery.

So use `cadvisor:8080` instead of `localhost:8080` in your configuration file.

Comment: yes!  thank you so much!  that solved one of the two (and makes sense)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by second issue but I also noticed there is a port `9080` in your configuration and your prometheus instance is exposing port `9090`, so there might be a typo? I have no clue about Prometheus configuration, so not sure about that.

Comment: yeah, they are close enough to almost look like a typo.  there are two containers I'm trying to report metrics from in Prometheus, cAdvisor on port 8080, and a container named tiingo, which is reporting metrics on port 9080.  there's nothing obviously different between them (aside from the port), so with your correction, I'm even more stumped why one is working and the other not